# Creating opening and closing stock with panda

Tags: python, pandas

HI I have following data

```
date                 qty  p_id  type    
2014-08-04 21:04:00   3   a     inward  
2014-08-04 22:04:00   3   a     outward 
2014-08-04 21:04:00   10  b     inward  
2014-08-04 10:04:00   5   b     outward 
2014-10-04 21:04:00   40  c     inward  
2014-11-04 21:04:00   5   c     outward 
2014-10-05 21:04:00   10  c     inward  
2014-09-05 21:04:00   4   b     outward
```

Code so far I have tried. It does not seems to be efficient and also data is not coming proper.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'date': ['2014-08-04 21:04:00','2014-08-04 22:04:00','2014-08-04 21:04:00','2014-08-04 10:04:00','2014-10-04 21:04:00','2014-11-04 21:04:00','2014-10-05 21:04:00','2014-09-05 21:04:00'], 
    'p_id'  :['a','a','b','b','c','c','c','b'],
    'qty' :[3,3,10,5,40,5,10,4], 
    'type' :['inward','outward','inward','outward','inward','outward','inward','outward'] 
})
inward = df['type'] == 0
outward = df['type'] == 1

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.type = df.type.map({0:'inward', 1:'outward'})

df.groupby(['p_id', 'type']).resample('D')['qty'].sum().unstack(1, fill_value=0)
df1 = df.groupby(['p_id', 'type']).resample('D')['qty'].sum().unstack(1, fill_value=0).reset_index()

df1.sort_values(['date', 'p_id'])
df1['opening'] = df1['closing'] = 0
for i in range(1, len(df1)):
    df1.loc[i, 'opening'] = (df1.loc[i-1, 'closing'])
    df1.loc[i, 'closing'] = (df1.loc[i, 'inward'] + df1.loc[i, 'opening']) - df1.loc[i, 'outward']
```

I'm trying to get the following result but failing.

```
Date        open    inward  outward close   p_id
2014-08-04  0       3       3       0       a
2014-08-04  0       10      5       5       b
2014-08-04  0       40      5       35      c
2014-08-05  5       0       4       1       b
2014-08-05  35      10      0       45      c
2014-08-06  1       0       0       1       b
2014-08-06  45      0       0       45      c
```

Comment: Please show your erroneous code, SO is not a code writing service

Comment: Hey @EdChum sorry for that, I have added code which I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question wasn't very clear, but I think that the following code should put you on the right track. Everything is commented in a way it should be clear what is going on.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2014-08-04 21:04:00','2014-08-04 22:04:00','2014-08-04 21:04:00','2014-08-04 10:04:00','2014-10-04 21:04:00','2014-11-04 21:04:00','2014-10-05 21:04:00','2014-09-05 21:04:00'],
    'p_id'  :['a','a','b','b','c','c','c','b'],
    'qty' :[3,3,10,5,40,5,10,4],
    'type' :['inward','outward','inward','outward','inward','outward','inward','outward']
})

# change datetime strings to datetime objects
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
# change the datetime to date
df.date = df.date.apply(lambda x:x.date())

# Use pivot_table in order to perform such operations
df = pd.pivot_table(data=df,columns="type", values="qty", index=["p_id","date"])

# replace nans with zeros
df = df.fillna(0)

# move multiindex back to the columns and start a new, default index
df = df.reset_index()

# add the opening and closing calculation (not efficient, but not the problematic part after all)
df["opening"]=0
df["closing"]=0
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'opening'] = (df.loc[i-1, 'closing'])
    df.loc[i, 'closing'] = (df.loc[i, 'inward'] + df.loc[i, 'opening']) - df.loc[i, 'outward']

# change the order of columns and index to the desired output outlay
df = df[["date","inward","outward","opening","closing","p_id"]]
df = df.set_index("date")
print df
```

That should produce something you wanted in a first place:

```
   type        inward  outward  opening  closing p_id
    date                                              
    2014-08-04     3.0      3.0      0.0      0.0    a
    2014-08-04    10.0      5.0      0.0      5.0    b
    2014-09-05     0.0      4.0      5.0      1.0    b
    2014-10-04    40.0      0.0      1.0     41.0    c
    2014-10-05    10.0      0.0     41.0     51.0    c
    2014-11-04     0.0      5.0     51.0     46.0    c
```

Comment: It's really helped me, but I'm still not able to get the result which I needed. Before looping through df if we can group by with p_id and date and then sort it by date the values will come properly.

Comment: Could you please edit your question in a way that you will provide the proper input data, that will eventually create exact the same result table that you want. Because, judging from your question and result sample, I think that my proposed solution satisfies the given criteria.

Comment: Hey Marjan you are right, your solution solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that I helped!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your result table (definition of open and closed)

```
import datetime as dt
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

TESTDATA=StringIO("""date;qty;p_id;type
2014-08-04 21:04:00;3;a;inward
2014-08-04 22:04:00;3;a;outward
2014-08-04 21:04:00;10;b;inward
2014-08-04 10:04:00;5;b;outward
2014-10-04 21:04:00;40;c;inward
2014-11-04 21:04:00;5;c;outward
2014-10-05 21:04:00;10;c;inward
2014-09-05 21:04:00;4;b;outward""")

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";")
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))

df = pd.pivot_table(df,  columns=['type'], values = ['qty'], index=['date', 'p_id'])
df.reset_index( inplace=True, drop=False)
df.columns = ['date', 'p_id', 'inward', 'outward']
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df
```

which gives:

```
    date    p_id    inward  outward
0   2014-08-04  a   3.0     3.0
1   2014-08-04  b   10.0    5.0
2   2014-09-05  b   0.0     4.0
3   2014-10-04  c   40.0    0.0
4   2014-10-05  c   10.0    0.0
5   2014-11-04  c   0.0     5.0
```